# Why can't bash find files when the location is stored in a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, unix

I am trying to write the `.pgpass` file if it does not exist in the postgres user's home directory.

Currently I have

```
local PASS="~postgres/.pgpass"
echo "*:*:*:*:$PWD" >> $PASS
```

and it fails with `~postgres/.pgpass: No such file or directory`.

However, not using the variable works.

```
echo "*:*:*:*:$PWD" >> ~postgres/.pgpass
```

What's the difference between the two? How can I store the file in a variable and get it work?

Comment: do you mean ~/postgres

Comment: Basically, the `~` is only expanded when it is not inside quotes (and when it follows a space, an equals sign or a colon in an assignment, and similar conditions).

Comment: Is ~/postgres directory exist?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A couple of things,

## Bash: `~` is a shell expansion.

`~` doesn't extually exist as a path.

```
f="~/"
ls $f
```

will error

```
ls: cannot access '~/': No such file or directory
```

Instead, use the variable `$HOME`

## Typo or wrong file: ~postgres/.pgpass

This is a typo, you want `~/.pgpass`, or `$HOME/.pgpass` on Unix. From [the pg docs on the Password File](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html)

> The file .pgpass in a user's home directory or the file referenced by PGPASSFILE can contain passwords to be used if the connection requires a password (and no password has been specified otherwise). On Microsoft Windows the file is named %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf (where %APPDATA% refers to the Application Data subdirectory in the user's profile).

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to create the file in the postgres user while logged in as root, how would i do that?

Comment: `>> $(getent passwd "postgres" | cut -d: -f6)/.pgpass`

Comment: @EvanCarroll `~user` will expand to a users home directory.

Answer (score 2):

```
local PASS=~postgres/.pgpass
echo "*:*:*:*:$PWD" >> "$PASS"
```